# Can I calculate a date from the year and day number?

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I have day of year data that I'm working with in a HighChart bubble chart. Data looks about like this:

```
[2009,265,10930],[2012,27,642],[2012,287,4929],[2010,119,1020]
```

The X value is the year. The Y value is the day of the year, so 119 is April 29, 265 is September 22. I'd like to actually format the Y axis as dates, but I haven't been able to find a clean way to do that. I could just reformat the data in Calc, but is there a way to calculate that in HighCharts directly?

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts it's not possible, you need to preprocess data before sending to Highcharts, just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1137/

Note: Highcharts requires sorted data for line/spline series.

```
var json = [
    [2009, 265, 10930],
    [2012, 27, 642],
    [2012, 287, 4929],
    [2010, 119, 1020]
],
    DAY = 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    jLen = json.length,
    data = [],
    i = 0;

for (; i < jLen; i++) {
    var p = json[i]; // point
    data.push([Date.UTC(p[0], 0, 1) + p[1] * DAY, p[2]])
}

// sort data for Highcharts
data.sort(function(a,b) { return a[0] - b[0]; } );

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```